# how to sort time values based on From time in using filters in angular

Tags: javascript, angularjs

This is my sample data:

```
{
    "day": "Sunday",
    "count": [{
        "desc": "sunday one event"
    }, {
        "j": [{
            "start": "11:00 pm"
        }, {
            "end": "11:51 pm"
        }]
    }, {
        "desc": "sunday second event"
    }, {
        "j": [{
            "start": "12:00 am"
        }, {
            "end": "12:06 am"
        }]
    }]
}
```

And then output will be:

```
sunday one event 
11:00 PM, 11:51 PM, 
sunday second event 
12:00 AM, 12:06 AM,
```

But I want to show data as:

```
sunday second event 
12:00 AM, 12:06 AM, 
sunday one event 
11:00 PM, 11:51 PM,
```

How to sort-out data based on timing (start-end)

Comment: are you get this from any db

Comment: yes getting from mongodb

Comment: you should sort the data from there only. can you post your mongodb query

Comment: @Vinoth nothing shown here suggests anything to do with mongodb ... try to keep additional requests relevant

Comment: without giving query how can i give the solution

Answer (score 0):

I think you should have a id on each row, then this line of code will sort you reverse order.
   "`<tr ng-repeat="obj in object | orderBy:propertyName:reverse">`"

Answer (score -1):

the best way is to store a Date object and compare the getTime(), of these object to sort by date.

Comment: a date object has no `time()`

Comment: @charlietfl Sorry ? And what is this : https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_gettime.asp

Comment: it is certainly not `time()` as you have incorrectly suggested

Comment: @charlietfl It's better like this ?